# Java: Getting input with Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()) and scan.nextInt()

Tags: java

I have a Java program below. At first, I tried to get input n as this

```
int n = sc.nextInt();
```

But the output was different than expected. It runs the first iteration without taking the userName. After changing to

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

It's working fine. What was wrong with "int n = sc.nextInt();"?

```
public class StringUserNameChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Number of usernames you want to enter
        int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        while (n-- != 0) {
            String userName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Your username is " + userName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: Just an Integer

Comment: if it's just an integer then `username` becomes nothing because there's nothing left to read (except probably an `\n` or something of that kind)

Answer (score 0):

When `sc.nextLine()` is used after `sc.nextInt()`, it will read a newline character after the integer input.

So, to run your code correctly, you'll have to use `sc.nextLine()` after `sc.nextInt()`, like this:

```
int n = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
while(n-- > 0) {
    String username = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Correct but badly explained.